# Declaration Errors

Tags: solidity

Newbie here: I'm getting so many errors trying to compile a simple Token contract. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it. Can anyone help please?

[image]
[image]

Compile contract failed: ["fs://7c1b8c34-918c-4ac2-951b-2acb02bce6e3/root/MadToken.sol:26:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.\n    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) \n    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).\nfs://7c1b8c34-918c-4ac2-951b-2acb02bce6e3/root/MadToken.sol:17:5: The previous declaration is here:\n    mapping(address => uint256) \n    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).\n","fs://7c1b8c34-918c-4ac2-951b-2acb02bce6e3/root/MadToken.sol:57:5: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.\n    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {\n    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).\nfs://7c1b8c34-918c-4ac2-951b-2acb02bce6e3/root/MadToken.sol:19:5: The previous declaration is here:\n    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) \n    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).\n","fs://7c1b8c34-918c-4ac2-951b-2acb02bce6e3/root/MadToken.sol:58:16: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.\n        return allowed[_owner][_spender];\n               ^-----^\n"]

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to post your actual code, and not a screenshot.

In this code, the compiler is telling you that you have duplicate identifier names.
Line 26 uses name `balanceOf` for the function name, but you have already named your mapping variable `balanceOf`

Similar problem with Line 57, you use `allowance` as the function name, but have already declared a mapping variable called `allowance`

You need to use unique names for all identifiers (variables, functions, classes etc)